# Changing the CSS of a div in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a problem I have created a directive which is doing ng-repeat on an array of objects

---Showing the value on gui------

Now I want that if I click on any div of this repeat that particular div's background color should change

I have tried something like this

```
link:function(scope,element,attributes){
    $(element).on('click',function(e){
    $(element).addClass('A');
    $(element).removeClass('B');
   })
    }
```

Comment: Add some codes. What have you  tried right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ng-class` directive to apply classes on specific occurences, in your case in combination with the `ng-click`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items"
     ng-class="{A: item.clicked, B: !item.clicked}"
     ng-click="item.clicked = !item.clicked">
    <!-- .. content -->
</div>
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/91jsj09L/1/) for example

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, but this will need more workaround.

```
<div ng-click=“changeBackground($event)”></div>

// In Controller
   $scope.changeBackground = function(event){
   event.target.style.background = “#000”;
   }
```

It would be better if you can submit your code.

Comment: Where is the directive the user requested? Why are you using native JavaScript DOM manipulations while using AngularJS? You should use `ng-style` or `ng-class`.